# CakePHP DB query not showing same results on different machines (array assoc vs array index)

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm using CakePHP to query some data from a database. The code was made in the *old-fashioned* way, doing the query directly from a string:

```
$query = "SELECT 
        SUM(IF(p2.status = 'ACTIVE', p2.stock, 0)) AS total_stock,
        Product.*,
        Brand.*,
        Merchant.*,
        Item.*,
        Tenant.*
    FROM
        products p2,
        products Product
            LEFT JOIN
        brands Brand ON Product.brand_id = Brand.id
            LEFT JOIN
        items Item ON Product.item_id = Item.id
            LEFT JOIN
        merchants Merchant ON Product.merchant_id = Merchant.id,
        tenants Tenant
    WHERE
        Tenant.id = Product.tenant_id
            AND Product.id = ?
            AND Product.group_hash = p2.group_hash
    GROUP BY Product.id";
    $product = $this->queryFirst($query, array($id));
```

The code is working fine, when I dump the `$product` variable it show an associative array like this:

> ```
> Array (
>   [0] => Array
>       (
>           [total_stock] => 0
>       )
>
>   [Product] => Array
>       (
>           [id] => 23640
>           [type] => PRODUCT
>           ...
> ```

So later I can do `someFunc($product['Product']['id']` and it works still fine.

I tried this same code in a recovery machine and now when I dump the results it shows:

> ```
> Array (
>   [0] => Array
>       (
>           [total_stock] => 0
>           [id] => 23640
>           [type] => PRODUCT
>           ...
>       )
> ```

And of course when I do `someFunc($product['Product']['id']` in the recovery it shows:

> NOTICE: index not found: Product

I checked the versions of CakePHP and PHP in both production and recovery machines. The CakePHP version for both is `2.4`.

The version of PHP in production is `5.5.25` and in recovery is `5.5.34`, so the recovery version is newer, it shouldn't be a problem, right?

The version of MySQL are

> **RECOVERY:** mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.49, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.2

and

> **PRODUCTION:** mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.42, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.3

I'm using the same Git branch on both to be sure. I believe the problem *could* be in one of the files not versioned, so I checked also the core.php config files for both but there are no relevant differences.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**:

The `queryFirst` function is defined like this:

```
function queryFirst($query, $params = array())
{
    $data = $this->query($query, $params);
    if (isset($data[0])) {
        return $data[0];
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: I think problem not on php side, but with data in db. Your machines have different data in tables.

Comment: The data in the recovery database is one day older than the one in production. But I still believe the results should be similar, I mean the array should have the same format, right?

Comment: Show body of `queryFirst()`

Comment: I've just added it to the question.

Comment: As I see it is just execution of query. Try to run query with the same parameters on different servers and compare results. Are they the same?

Comment: No, they are not the same. One shows an array like this `array([Product] => Array)` and the other like this `array([0] => Array)`. Otherwise the data is the same.

Comment: `someFunc($product['Product']['id'];)` suggests that in array `$product` exist key `Product` and in array `$product['Product']` exist key `id`. But in your case `queryFirst` will return `Array   ( [total_stock] => 0)` (it means without key `Product`)

Comment: It works in production, it returns array([Product] => array)

Comment: Look at your `queryFirst`. This method returns array. In one case(on production) array looks like this: `['Product' => _something_here_, one_more_key => _something_here_, etc..]`. In second case method returns `[key1 => _something_here_, key2 => _something_here_]` but without key `Product`. And this is the reason. Try to add before `someFunc` next verification: `if (isset($product['Product']['id'])) { someFunc($product['Product']['id'] } else { # something here }`. The problem will disappear.

Comment: I know that's the why, my question is why it behaves differently in the two machines.

Comment: Are you sure that sql-query returns the same result? I mean raw sql-query with the same `Product.id`. Could you show results of queries from different db?

Answer (score 0):

### Different versions of MySQL

Although I can't find a specific reference, this has come up before and is almost certainly down to the version of MySQL.

### Why does it happen

This behavior is down to the way CakePHP asks mysql "what table does this field belong to?" for result sets, to determine the array keys used - and the answer varies depending on the version of MySQL. In 2.4 the relevant method is [getColumnMeta](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.getcolumnmeta.php), in 1.x it was [mysql_fetch_field](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-field.php). This also manifests itself when views are used and MySQL sometimes returns the source table name, sometimes returns the view name and sometimes returns nothing.

With the query in the question the second field in the result set is `id` (Product id). On one server `getColumnMeta` returns `Product` for table, and on the other it returns null, with the end result being that the query's returned array structure differs.

The relevant code is [here](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.4.0/lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/Database/Mysql.php#L234-L258) (what table does this belong to?) and [here](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.4.0/lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/Database/Mysql.php#L260-L279) (reindexing of results to be `[table][field]` indexed) if you'd like to look around and confirm/deny whether this is the cause in your case.

This undesirable behavior is also the main reason why CakePHP stopped doing that in 3.x, and always uses queries of the form:

```
SELECT Foos.id AS `Table__field`
```

Where the field alias determines the array indexes used in the results.

### How to fix it

You may be able to affect this by aliasing fields or being explicit with the returned fields (not using `.*`), *maybe*.

Alternatively, convert the `query` to a `find('first', $params)` call - as CakePHP can consume it's own dogfood :). The `query` method should be avoided unless absolutely necessary, the existence of `queryFirst` (and the query in the question) suggests using query unnecessarily.

Comment: The  problem of changing it to CakePHP syntax is that there are over 3000 queries in the whole project!

Comment: @VladimirNul that's a self-made problem, but in any case you need to (you haven't yet) confirm the cause to be able to decide what action to then take.

Comment: The project was already made that way when I started working on it. I have change the parts that I need to modify to the *Cake way*, but still there's lot to change and of course probably we'll never change everything. I manage to solve this by executing the program in production pointing to the recovery database and it works, so it should be some problem with that server.

Comment: That indicates/suggests it is the version of the mysql _client_ which is the relevant factor. As a general comment: Irrespective of whether I've identified the cause or not it is a bad idea to have any difference between environments precisely because it causes this kind of "only in production/only on the backup machine" heisen-problems. Also, probably obvious, be extremely careful upgrading your apps, since you know that different (patch level!) versions of something (mysql client) causes the app to break because of the way it's written. Good luck.